# regex match a word after a particular word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I created a regex for matching a string which could be possibly something like shown below:

```
then &quot;hello I am here&quot; blah blah
```

**or**

```
then hello blah blah
```

I am trying to match the word just after `then`. For above strings the expected outputs are

```
&quot;hello I am here&quot;   //if the words are in quotes
```

or

```
hello
```

I tried this regex `&quot;(\w*[\s]*)*&quot;|(?<=\bthen\s)(\w+)` , which is working fine online but showing error in firefox. Error

[image]

Comment: You are using lookbehind `(?<=...)` which is not supported by javascript

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am sure that you mean `?<=` (If I remove this, there are no errors). any other way to make it work?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RVfdr/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var regex = /then\s*(&quot;(.*?)&quot;|(\w*))\s*.*/

function getSomething(string){
    var arr = regex.exec(string);
    console.log(arr);
    return arr.length > 1 ? arr[1] : undefined;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RVfdr/3/)